# Edit and update only numeric text in XML file while creating different versions of the XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, python-itertools

I am trying to do a variability study on an xml file. An example psuedo code is shown below.

```
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
```

I would like to dynamically change (say multiply by 1.5) each text in the xml that is all numeric values e.g. >2< or >141100< or and NOT >1.21$/kg< or >>4.1$/kg<<. I need to save each text variation as a different xml file (e.g. when I change rank of Liechtenstein to 3, save the xml file as LiechtensteinRank1.5).

My goal is to transform each of these text inputs and save all versions from each change and then batch run the xml files together later. The xml is relatively deep nested 200,000 lines and up to 10 Different child nodes.

I have only been able to extract the text as below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("Ywepr.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for text in root.itertext():
    print repr(text)   
charlie = file.writelines(root.itertext())
```

All suggestions welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to do a traversal of the tree in order to do this. The reason is that you need to actually update the text of an XML elements in place in order for the output to be correct.

To do a traversal of etree's nodes, you'll want to use Element.getchildren(). This returns a list of all of the children elements of this element. Because an English description turned out to be pretty gnarly, I'm going to just launch into code.

```
def traversal(elem):
    text = elem.text
    # do work here

    for node in elem.getchildren():
        traversal(node)
```

This is a pretty classic recursive solution to a tree traversal, where you go node by node, doing work and visiting all child nodes. Eventually, you end up visiting them all. Note that this solution requires your XML data to fit into memory, but it seems that you've already loaded it, so you should be in good shape here.

I also should touch on what you need to do in order to do your text matching. I recommend using a regular expression if your condition is as simple as 'all digits'. The below should be enough to get you started, I hope.

```
import re
digitsRegex = re.compile(r'\d+$')
digitsRegex.match('12345')
```